# Does DBMS_XSLProcessor process Stylesheets with extensions?

Tags: oracle, plsql, xslt

I have been trying to get DBMS_XSLProcessor ( the pl/sql package ONLY) to get it to transform a simple XSL which has a java extension as per the acceptable convention for processing XSL stylesheets with Oracle supplied tools (the XSL Processor package within the database as well as the java based XML Developers Kit- XDK outside the database).

Here is a sample xml document (*ceil.xml*) (slightly modified from the math.xml sample given in the XSLT Examples of the 11gR1 database )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <n1>2.4</n1>
</doc>
```

Here is my XSL called ceil.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:mth="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/java.lang.Math"
>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    Should ciel n1 to "3": <xsl:value-of select="mth:ceil(//n1)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my simple pl/sql anonymous block:

```
DECLARE
    indoc VARCHAR2(2000);
    xsldoc VARCHAR2(2000);
    myParser dbms_xmlparser.Parser;
    indomdoc dbms_xmldom.domdocument;
    xsltdomdoc dbms_xmldom.domdocument;
    xsl dbms_xslprocessor.stylesheet;
    outdomdocf dbms_xmldom.domdocumentfragment;
    outnode dbms_xmldom.domnode;
    proc dbms_xslprocessor.processor;
    buf varchar2(2000);

BEGIN

    indoc := '<?xml version="1.0"?><doc><n1>2.4</n1></doc>';

    dbms_output.put_line( 'Input document [' || indoc || ']' );

    xsldoc :=
        '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:mth="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/java.lang.Math">
        <xsl:template match="/">
        Should ciel n1 to "3": <xsl:value-of select="mth:ceil(//n1)"/>
        </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>';

    dbms_output.put_line( 'before creating new parser:' || systimestamp );
    myParser := dbms_xmlparser.newParser;
    dbms_output.put_line( 'before parsing XML Doc:' || systimestamp );
    dbms_xmlparser.parseBuffer(myParser, indoc);

    indomdoc := dbms_xmlparser.getDocument(myParser);
    dbms_output.put_line( 'before pulling parsed DOM of XML :' || systimestamp );
    dbms_xmldom.writetobuffer(indomdoc, buf);
    dbms_output.put_line(buf);

    dbms_xmlparser.parseBuffer(myParser, xsldoc);
    xsltdomdoc := dbms_xmlparser.getDocument(myParser);
    dbms_output.put_line( 'before pulling parsed DOM of XSL :' || systimestamp );

    xsl := dbms_xslprocessor.newstylesheet(xsltdomdoc, '');
    proc := dbms_xslprocessor.newProcessor;

    --apply stylesheet to DOM document
    dbms_output.put_line( 'before processing XSL:' || systimestamp );
    outdomdocf := dbms_xslprocessor.processxsl(proc, xsl, indomdoc);
    outnode := dbms_xmldom.makenode(outdomdocf);

    dbms_xmldom.writeToBuffer( outnode, buf );
    dbms_output.put_line( 'after writing to output buffer:' || systimestamp );
    dbms_output.put_line( 'Length of output =[' || LENGTH( buf ) || ']' );
    dbms_output.put_line(buf);

END;
/
```

Running this on an SQL Prompt gives me the following output (error):

```
Input document [<?xml version="1.0"?><doc><n1>2.4</n1></doc>]
before creating new parser:19-AUG-11 03.32.33.471688000 PM -07:00
before parsing XML Doc:19-AUG-11 03.32.33.472413000 PM -07:00
before pulling parsed DOM of XML :19-AUG-11 03.32.33.476298000 PM -07:00
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
<n1>2.4</n1>
</doc>

before pulling parsed DOM of XSL :19-AUG-11 03.32.33.490319000 PM -07:00
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00607: Invalid reference: 'ceil'.
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR", line 759
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR", line 782
ORA-06512: at line 44
```

However this same code works on the UNIX prompt when using oraxsl utility...

```
-->oraxsl ceil.xml ceil.xsl
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>

Should ciel n1 to "3": 3
-->
```

Any ideas why the java extension, which is just referring to a built-in function not working?
This is for an Oracle Enterprise Edition Database Release 11.1.0.6.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the Oracle XSLT proecssor, but I can tell you that there are no standards for calling Java from XSLT - each processor does its own thing.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I meant to say XSL Standard loosely. Have edited my question.